# Why can other people work abroad but my partner can't - is this discrimination?

Tags: management, human-resources, ethics, people-management, discrimination

My partner is really going through it at the moment... she works in the UK at a tech startup going through some fairly aggressive acquisition management changes, which are having affects on morale.

She put in a request to work from (her home country) Argentina for 15 working days - taking some holidays either side - bringing the total up to a full calendar month away.

The powers that be have not given her manager a straight answer for over a week, citing things like "well she has to have extenuating circumstances" etc

But meanwhile, other colleagues in the past have:

- worked from Italy for over a week
- left to go Portugal when covid hit and stayed for x2 months
- left to the US for up to x2 months, non-covid related, causing huge disruption to teamwork and scheduling because of the time difference
- others were allowed to work from Greece

Nowhere in her contract is this request prohibited, so she believes she's being discriminated against because other people have had no trouble whatsoever.

She believes that the reason for their hesitancy has something to do with the country she's travelling to. Other than that, it's a mystery and quite frankly unacceptable given that she's pregnant and can't fly next year. This isn't how you look after people.

**There are three outcomes to this:**

- she gets what she wants
- they force her to take unpaid leave for the 15 days
- no offer and that she can't go

**How does she get what she wants? Is a formal complaint going to help here?**

Comment: How can you say that your partner can't work abroad if "The powers that be have not given her manager a straight answer"?

Comment: @sf02 see questions at bottom of post 

Comment: Regulatory and diplomatic relations between the UK and Argentina are probably very different from what they are with Italy, Portugal, Greece, or the US, especially if any of those examples from coworkers are from before Brexit, which really only went into effect at the beginning of this year. It's apples and oranges.

Comment: `left to the US for up to x2 months, non-covid related, causing huge disruption to teamwork and scheduling because of the time difference` maybe they noticed that too and are no longer allowing people to work from places with too much of a time difference?

Answer (score 9):

First things first. **A week is probably not enough time for the company to make a decision.** I'm sure some companies could decide very quickly, but plenty couldn't. Don't assume they are going to refuse you because they haven't made a super-speedy decision.

**You don't know the circumstances of the other workers.** You got feedback that "she has to have extenuating circumstances". Maybe all the others had extenuating circumstances. The company is unlikely to tell you about whatever personal circumstances they had. You haven't said what the reason for your partner wanting to work abroad is.

There are lots of things that influence a company when they decide whether to allow someone to do this or not, including:

- Time zone difficulties
- Whether the work can reasonably be done remotely
- How valuable the worker is
- How trusted the worker is
- Infrastructure issues like internet
- Tax issues
- Legal issues
- Healthcare and insurance issues
- Are circumstances forcing the employee to go abroad, or is it just a preference?

And no, a formal complaint is not going to help. It will probably make things worse.

Comment: On top of tax issues are just general regulatory issues. The company could have arrangements with those other countries that make it possible for employees to work there (maybe they have an actual office location) they may not have with Argentina. This is especially true if those other examples happened before Brexit was completed, since OP's company is in the UK.

Comment: In the UK, tax issues usually kick in after ~ 6 months so likely those are not applicable to short-term escapades.

Answer (score 8):

> She believes that the reason for their hesitancy has something to do with the country she's travelling to.

Most countries have different tax and other work regulations.  These differences can create hard situations for companies to allow "work from anywhere" scenarios.  If her company does not already have an office in Argentina, and therefore a legal presence, the regulations could make it hard for her company to support her request.

I know of companies that tried to be very flexible during Covid restrictions, but had specific places that were not allowed based on the location of the parent company and any of their foreign offices.  It could be that the rest of Europe(even after Brexit) and the US are more amenable than Argentina

I am not an accountant or a lawyer, so you should investigate this with a qualified professional to see if that is part of the delay.  I would certainly recommend that before taking a hard line with her employer.  You say it is unacceptable for her, but it could also be unacceptable  for them.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try and break this down:

> is this discrimination?

To some extent, yes. However, discrimination is perfectly allowed - I'm allowed to give workers different rights depending on their job role, their skill level and all sorts of other things. What is not allowed is discrimination on the basis of any of the [protected characteristics](https://www.equalityhumanrights.com/en/equality-act/protected-characteristics) defined in the Equality Act 2010, which does include race.

> She believes that the reason for their hesitancy has something to do with the country she's travelling to.

Assuming you can prove this, while country is *correlated* with race, the business might have legitimate reasons for not allowing it. If it came to an employment tribunal, you'd have to convince the panel that the whatever business reasons were being claimed weren't legitimate.

> The powers that be have not given her manager a straight answer for over a week

You and your partner are being unreasonable if you expect an answer to a complicated question like this in a week. Other answers here explain why it's complicated.

> How does she get what she wants?

Wait a bit and see what the answer is. If it's no, the answer is almost certainly "she doesn't get what she wants". She of course does have the option of resigning.

> Is a formal complaint going to help here?

Almost certainly not. Unless they're fools, her employer would take professional advice, and come up with enough business reasons that you wouldn't be able to win at an employment tribunal.